# How to wrap text in css

Tags: html, css

I got some long text and I want to an auto-line break system. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my div;

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" style="font-size: 100%; text-align: left;">some long text here!</div>
```

I tried some solutions but it didn't worked for me.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: visible;
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I am getting same output like above. When I change the width of this div, div's width is changing but text remains same.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" style="font-size: 100%; text-align: left; word-wrap: break-word !important;
            overflow: visible !important;">fadsfsd dsf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdffafdsafads dsf sadf asdf sadf asdf sdsdfasdfadsfdasfsdds sadf sadf sadf asdf asfsdfsdfasdfadsfdasfdsa sdaf sadf sadfas d
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPQRKK - it works as expected, both on Chrome and Firefox [even changing the overflow]. In which browser are you trying?

Comment: If you put spaces inside that long "word" the text will break, the default break works for words since there is no space between characters `fdsafdsa` it is just one long word.... If you want to break the word is another thing

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I didn't get why it is now working for me. Can some css overrides this style?

Comment: I couldn't tell: you should post a link to a page (fiddle) where the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css style it will work:

```
.alert alert-warning{
width:98%;/*set the width by your needs*/
white-space: normal;}
```

Comment: When I add white-space it worked.thanks for your answer.

Comment: @hellzone, then you have a different white-space defined elsewhere

Comment: He need just for auto-line break. For that it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: visible;
width: 800px;
```

word-wrap only works if a `width` is specified.

Comment: please, could you post a reference about the need of having a width defined? On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) I haven't seen it.

Comment: I've had a previous experience in which word-wrap: wouldn't work, but when I defined a width it did, perhaps it was just because of the rest of my code, interesting though, you're correct it isn't mentioned on MDN